# How do I select text in RichTextBox while keeping keyboard focus in another TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I'm working on a chat window in WPF that hosts a Forms.RichTextBox.

```
<WindowsFormsHost x:Name="wfh">
   <wf:RichTextBox x:Name="txtMain" HideSelection="False" ReadOnly="True" Multiline="True"/>
</WindowsFormsHost>
```

Below this `RichTextBox` is a regular WPF `TextBox`.

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtSend" TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True"/>
```

I'd like the keyboard focus to stay on the `TextBox`, yet still allow the user to select text in the WFH's `RichTextBox` and scroll.

I've tried changing the keyboard focus on `MouseUp` in `txtMain`, however then I cannot scroll, and it's not possible to copy using Ctrl+C.

Any ideas?

Comment: I am not sure that would be possible. Usually when you are scrolling down or selecting text in some component the focus should be on that component. Why do you need to do this, if I may ask?

Comment: Mostly for a better user experience. Since this is a chat window, I'd like the user to be able to always be ready to type. Note that programs like Google Talk have this functionality (keyboard focus on textbox, but still able to select/copy text elsewhere).

Comment: @Arsham It is possible using `FocusScope`

Comment: @lll Cool! never thought that was possible to do. I will look at the link. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at this [sample](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38507/Using-the-WPF-FocusScope). If you want multiple focus you have to use `FocusScope`.

Sample code from the link

```
static void OnGotKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
{
    IInputElement focusedElement = e.NewFocus;
    for (DependencyObject d = focusedElement as DependencyObject; 
        d != null; d = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(d)) {
        if (FocusManager.GetIsFocusScope(d)) {
            d.SetValue(FocusManager.FocusedElementProperty, focusedElement);
            if (!(bool)d.GetValue(IsEnhancedFocusScopeProperty)) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, looking over the sample!